# ‘YYSTYPE’ has no member named '--' for union type

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex

I have declared the YYSTYPE union as

```
%union
{
        char* stringValue;
        union int_double_string* ids;
}
```

`int_double_string` is declared as

```
union int_double_string
{
        short type;     //0:int 1:double 2:string
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        char* stringValue;
};
```

Some tokens

```
%token <stringValue> KEY
%token <int_double_string> VALUE
%token <stringValue> COMMENT    
%type <stringValue> pair
%type <int_double_string> key_expr
```

But where-ever I use token `VALUE`, it gives me that common error.

```
‘YYSTYPE’ has no member named ‘int_double_string’

pair:
        KEY ws '=' ws VALUE     {
                char S5[15];
                addPair($1, $5);   //Error here and where-ever I use $5 in this function
                ...
```

Why is this so though I've declared it correctly? I've used the variable in my lex file as well. Its showing no error there.

lex file

```
{integer}       {
                yylval.ids = malloc(sizeof(union int_double_string));
                yylval.ids->type = 0;
                yylval.ids->intValue = atoi(yytext);
                return VALUE;
        }
```

I think it has something to with the concept of union inside a union.

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
‘YYSTYPE’ has no member named ‘int_double_string’
```

The id in `%type <id>` and `%token <id>` needs to be a field in the `yyunion`.

So, the tokens defined as type int_double_string need to be type ids

```
%token <int_double_string> VALUE
%type <int_double_string> key_expr
```

like this

```
%token <ids> VALUE
%type <ids> key_expr
```

And the second argument to `addPair` should be a `union int_double_string*`

In typical yacc usage you would put all these fields:

```
short type;     //0:int 1:double 2:string
int intValue;
double doubleValue;
char *stringVal;
```

Into the yyunion itself and not have a union field in yyunion. I'm not saying you can't but it is unusual.